# Syncing tasks from SharePoint to Outlook for individuals

Tags: client

When syncing tasks from SharePoint to Outlook, will the system allow you to sync only your tasks and not the whole task list?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the SharePoint Server version you use and on your setup. For SP2013 it should only sync your tasks. SP2010 will sync all tasks.

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2876938/syncing-task-lists-in-microsoft-sharepoint-server-2013-with-outlook